# Pagination with search option in Angular2

Tags: search, angular, pagination, ng2-bootstrap

I'm getting the problem with pagination on search. Pagination is working fine but when I used search box and enter some letters then the results vary. Because of varying result, pagination behave irregular.

I'm using `PaginationModule`  from `'ng2-bootstrap'`

I'm getting `users` list with pagination.. Here is my `users.component.ts`

```
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
     users: IUser[];
     term : string = '';

     public itemsPerPage: number = 1;
     public totalItems: number = 0;
     public currentPage: number = 1;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers(){
    this.dataService.getUsers(this.currentPage, this.itemsPerPage)
        .subscribe((users: PaginatedResult<IUser[]>) => {
                this.users = users;
            this.totalItems = users['pagination']['TotalItems'];       
        });
    }

  pageChanged(event: any, term: string): void {
      this.currentPage = event.page;
       if(term != '')
          this.search(term);
       else
        this.getUsers();
  }

  search(term) {
    this.dataService.searchUserList(term, this.currentPage, this.itemsPerPage)
        .subscribe((items : PaginatedResult<IUser[]>) => {
            this.totalItems = items['pagination']['TotalItems'];
            this.users = items;
      });
   }
}
```

This is `users.component.html`

```
     //Search input box
 <input #term (keyup)="search(term.value)" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" autofocus>
     //pagination
 <pagination [boundaryLinks]="true" [totalItems]="totalItems" [itemsPerPage]="itemsPerPage" [(ngModel)]="currentPage" class="pagination-sm"
                previousText="&lsaquo;" nextText="&rsaquo;" firstText="&laquo;" lastText="&raquo;" (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event, term.value)"></pagination>
```

The problem is when I'm at `page:3` and search something.. And the result I got have only 1 page after search then I got this error

`ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '3'. Current value: '1'.`

I know this is because  I was at `page:3` and after search result I have only `1 page` that's why pagination behave irregualr.

Is there any solution for this?